# Override styling for md-autocomplete (change clear button icon)

Tags: angularjs-material

I have a component that contains an `md-autocomplete`.  This component is essentially being used as a searchable select list.

So, I'd like to change the icon of the clear-button from the 'X' to a down arrow.

[image]

I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40655886/), but that doesn't work for me, because I need the button to remain clickable.

**Is there a way I can override the button styling in the component's CSS to specify a different icon to be used?**